# Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required file

Tags: wordpress, xampp

When I tried to install fresh  Wordpress package in the local system(Window 10), I got this error:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-blog-header.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') 
>          in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php on line 17

For Localhost am using XAMPP server.

Comment: Please check folder permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same error.
The solution is to simply extract the WordPress zip folder content into `htdocs` ( if you are using xampp ) or into `www` (if you are using wampp ).
Just do not extract it somewhere else and then into htdocs, or else it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

It may be occurred due to some files are missing..

Download a fresh copy of the WordPress .zip file to your computer, unzip it, and use that to copy up all files and folders EXCEPT the wp-config.php file and the /wp-content/directory. You may need to delete the old wp-admin and wp-include folders.

Note- Please backup files and database before doing any actions.